# Flex 3.5 - Form alignment

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder

I made this form, but as you can see the first column of fields are not properly aligned.
I tried to do it with the graphical editor but it just won't do it.

[image: flex form]

Here is the code :

```
<mx:TitleWindow
    id="SearchTitleWindow"
    title="Recherche"
    showCloseButton="true"
    horizontalAlign="right"
    width="627.8656"
    height="201" x="267" y="275">

    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="116">
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:FormItem label="Numéro voie : "  width="140.71146" height="21.007908">
                <mx:TextInput id="numVoie" width="41.916996" height="21.007908"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:FormItem label="Nature voie : " >
                <mx:TextInput id="natVoie" width="100"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:FormItem label="Nom voie* : " >
                <mx:TextInput id="nomVoie" width="163.91306" height="21.007908"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox width="597.33203" height="20.98814">
            <mx:FormItem label="Complement :   "  width="599.3083" height="21.007908">
                <mx:TextInput id="Complement" width="497.92493" height="21.007908"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:FormItem label="Code postal* : " >
                <mx:TextInput id="codePostal" width="101.581024" height="21.996048"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:FormItem label="Commune* : " >
                <mx:TextInput id="Commune" width="294.13046" height="21.007908"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:FormItem label="Coordonnées : " >
                    <mx:TextInput id="coordOne" width="169.01187" height="21.007908"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:FormItem label="   " >
                <mx:TextInput id="coordTwo" width="169.40714" height="21.007908"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:Button id="geocoderTourneeSearchBtn"
                       styleName="button"
                       width="120"
                       label="Géocoder"/>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:ControlBar horizontalAlign="right" height="45">
        <mx:Button id="cancelTourneeSearchBtn"
                   styleName="button"
                   width="200"
                   label="Annuler"/>
        <mx:Button id="searchTourneeSearchBtn" 
                   styleName="button"
                   width="200"
                   label="Rechercher"/>
    </mx:ControlBar>
</mx:TitleWindow>
```

The weird height and width parameters have been set by the graphical editor.
Any idea how do do it?

Thank you.

PS : I can only use flex SDK 3.5

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not using the `Form` container anywhere in the code you've provided.

A Flex `Form` works with `FormItems` to figure out the width of the largest label. As such it will then be able to adjust the position (or perhaps dimensions) of each `FormItem` so the labels can be right aligned.

You've got a complex form where on some rows there are multiple form items. It's not clear to me how this will work w/respect to getting a proper form layout. But I'm thinking the developers may have anticipated this too.

Here's how a form should be specified in MXML:

```
<mx:Form>
    <mx:FormItem label="label 1">
        <mx:TextInput id="textInput1" />
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="label 2">
        <mx:TextInput id="textInput2" />
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

I'm not exactly sure how you should handle multiple `FormItems` on the same row. I'd try using the `HBox` that contains 2 or more `FormItem` controls. However, I wouldn't spend a lot of time on that.

You might find that using a constraint based layout with rows and columns makes this easier to implement. The `Canvas` container supports layout constraints like: top, bottom, left, right. It also allows you to setup your own grid with the `constrainColumns` and `constraintRows` arrays.

Comment: Actually I am using it I just forgot it when I copied/pasted this piece of code

Comment: @sliders_alpha if you still need help, I would recommend trying to create a simple application that reproduces the problem, then edit your question and show that code. Or at least update your question to include the proper code :) It's hard to offer a solution if we don't have all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this problem occur due to varying width of label. I have also faced the same problem in my project. And i was fix this problem by setting the equal width of each formItem label. You should set the width of every formItem label with width of longest length label.

In your form, label "Coordonnées" have the maximum width. So, you set the width of each formItem label with the width of "Coordonnées" label.

Comment: It should be noted that the Flex `Form` and `FormItem` work together to solve this problem of variable label widths. So this is not really necessary, if you build the form properly :)

Comment: I solved this problem by not using a form, instead I uses the Label and textField tags then I call a method when clicking the button